# Tastypie: Filtering by ToManyField

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have the following resources:

```
class SpecResource(ModelResource):
    results = fields.ToManyField('(...).ResultResource', 'result_set', full=True)
    (...)

class ResultResource(ModelResource):
    number = fields.IntegerField()
    spec = fields.ForeignKey('(...).SpecResource', 'spec')
    (...)
```

so that when I look at a spec JSON it includes a list of the results that have a ForeignKey to that spec. Now I'd like to filter the results that show up when I look at a spec JSON, and I'd like to be able to filter through the URL in the way that you'd filter a list of specs by a field of the specs. Is that possible?

To illustrate further, I'd like to go to "/api/spec/1/?number=5" and get the same JSON that I'd get if I went to "/api/spec/1/" *except* that the results field only contains those results that have number = 5.

Is this possible within tastypie's framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since you posted here, but you may find a piece of solution in the answer @kroolik gave me in a similar situation, to build a filter on a 'nested' ToManyField-related resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035610/1387495

Here is the main idea:

> You can extend your *attribute* argument you've passed to the *results* field with a full-scale function and reuse the *ResultResource*.
>   The **res.obj_get_list** handles building and applying filters as defined per your *ResultResource*. You just need to filter it further on **parent_id**.

In the code:

```
class SpecResource(ModelResource):
    results = fields.ToManyField('(...).ResultResource', attribute=lambda bundle: filter_result_items(bundle), full=True)
```

with

```
def filter_result_items(bundle):
    res = ResultResource()
    new_bundle = Bundle(request=bundle.request)
    objs = res.obj_get_list(new_bundle)
    return objs.filter(parent_id=bundle.obj.pk)
```

Once again, thank @kroolik, who showed me this trick.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JB. Noted, I edited my answer to fit your requirements. Thanks!

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac This edited post does now provide an explicit answer to the question. Thanks.