# Tastypie Authorization and ToManyField

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I'm trying to implement a resource containing a `ToManyField`, but I'd like the objects returned by the `ToManyField` to be limited by the requesting user.

I've tried the following, to no avail.

```
from django.db import models
from my_project.apps.my_app.models import MyUser
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields

###
# MODELS
###
class TieFighter(models.Model):
    pilot = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    fighter_class = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='Interceptor')
    squadron = models.ForeignKey(Squadron, related_name='tie_fighters')

class Squadron(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

###
# AUTHORIZATION
###
class TieFighterAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(pilot=bundle.request.user)

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.pilot == bundle.request.user

###
# RESOURCES
###
class TieFighterResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authorization = TieFighterAuthorization()
        queryset = TieFighter.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'tie_fighters'

class SquadronResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = Squadron.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'squadrons'

    tie_fighters = fields.ToManyField(TieFighterResource, null=True, full=True, attribute='tie_fighters')
```

Notice that the `pilot` relation, which I'd like to filter by, only exists in TieFighter.  Thus I created a special `Authorization` subclass for TieFighterResource, which enforces that the resource only returns tie fighters whose pilots match the requesting user.  This works when I call the TieFighterResource endpoint directly.  But when I call SquadronResource, the constraint is gone; all tie fighters within that squadron are listed, regardless of who the pilot/requesting user is.

***Please note:*  I want to filter out `TieFighter`s on each Squadron, but still return all `Squadron`s.  That is to say, I don't want my filtering out of `TieFighter`s to prevent a user from seeing `Squadron`s with an empty `tie_fighter` relation.**

Suggestions?

Comment: You need to create another authorization class for squadron with a backwards relational query.

Comment: Not sure that would achieve what I need.  I don't want to a list of `Squadron`s filtered by those that have `TieFighter`s containing the request user.

Rather, I want to return ALL squadrons, but I want their `tie_fighters` attribute to only list `TieFighter`s containing the request user.  In other words, I want to filter out `TieFighter`s on each `Squadron`.

Answer (score 1):

In `read_list` filter by `tie_fighters__pilot`.

In `read_detail` fetch all `fie_fighters` and filter by `pilot`.

```
class SquadronAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(tie_fighters__pilot=bundle.request.user)

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.tie_fighters.all().filter(pilot=bundle.request.user).count() <> 0
```

Comment: This filters out `Squadron`s not containing `TieFighter`s not belonging to the requesting user.  But, rather, I want to return ALL `Squadron`s, except that I want their `tie_fighters` attribute to only list `TieFighter`s containing the request user. In other words, I want to filter out `TieFighter`s on each Squadron, but still return all `Squadron`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I resolved the issue.  You can filter on relational fields in TastyPie by passing in a callable as the named argument `attribute`.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035610/1387495.

```
from tastypie.bundle import Bundle

'''
Enforce the TieFighterResource's ACL.
'''
def enforce_acl(bundle):
    res = TieFighterResource()
    new_bundle = Bundle(request=bundle.request)
    objs = res.obj_get_list(new_bundle)
    return objs

class SquadronResource(ModelResource):    
    ...        
    tie_fighters = fields.ToManyField(TieFighterResource, null=True, full=True, attribute=enforce_acl)
```

Ideally, this would be built into TastyPie; I think it's a fair assumption that the authorization logic of the resource you passed into your `ToManyField` would constrain the field's result set without any additional configuration.  I will create a pull request when I have time.